# How to escape quotes in solr nested query syntax?

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I.e. I want to search for phrase with nested queries syntax
so

```
_query_:"{!dismax qf=myfield}"how now""
```

How to solve this for first level?
How to solve this for any level? `_query_:"_query_:"{!dismax qf=myfield}"how now"""`

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to dereference the parameter in the local params:

`_query_:"{!dismax qf=myfield v=$query1}"` then at the end of the url add `query1="how how"` and do that foreach query but change to query2 query3 etc.

see bottom of this page

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams